# Spring Boot RESTful Web Service

Tags: java, spring, rest, tomcat, request

I am using eclipse and spring framework to make a simple Rest service following this tutorial [Spring Boot RESTful Web Service Tutorial - Java REST API](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_859wl7Smm8). It all works fine on my desktop pc, but then I tried to copy the project
and open it on laptop with the same version of eclipse...

The problem is when I start the app, I can not open localhost:8080, and I dont get a "Whitelabel Error Page".... just 404. The same is when I try to invoke the rest controller method.

When I look at console, on pc I see this:

[image]

But I have a slight different log on laptop:

[image]

I will post the classes here also, so anyone can tell me what could be the reason?

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class App {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
        }

    }
```

---

```
package com.start.contract.controllers;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.start.contract.datamodel.Contract;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(ContractController.CONTRACT_BASE_URI)
public class ContractController {

    public static final String CONTRACT_BASE_URI = "svc/v1/contracts";

    @RequestMapping(value = "{contractNumber}")
    public Contract getContract(@PathVariable final int contractNumber)
    {

        Contract contract = new Contract();
        contract.setName("Djomla");
        contract.setId(contractNumber);
        return contract;
    }

}
```

---

```
package com.start.contract.datamodel;

public class Contract {

    private String name;
    private int id;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Contract [name=").append(name).append(", id=").append(id).append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: so you are saying that logs tell you that tomcat started at 8080 and browser says it cant connect to localhost:8080??

Comment: looking at your laptop's log, it has not created the mapping while it started so you are getting 404. pretty weird problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After manu things, what worked for me was changing the pom.xml settings,
I downcreased the spring boot version to

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.13.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

instead of

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

... and now it works on my laptop too... I just still don't know whz would it be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

add this to application.properties file.

```
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=true
```